# Button not appearing after switching from grid to place in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on something and decided I wanted to use place instead of grid because of the variety in placement. The issue is that it's not appearing on the frame at all, I'm not sure why because the button under it works if I use grid, but place isn't working at all for some reason.
Here's my code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.frame.pack()
    practiceButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = f"Practice Terms", font = ('Louis George   Cafe', 20), command=lambda: self.showFrame('review'))
    practiceButton.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
    self.root.geometry("750x750")
    self.root.mainloop()
```

The button in question is the practiceButton.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frame has a default width and height of 1 pixel. Using `place`, the frame won't expand to fit its children. You put your button inside this 1x1 frame.

You must give the frame a width and height, or stop using `place` if you want it to be visible. I recommend using `pack` in this specific example since it only requires one line of code. Both `pack` and `grid` will by default cause the parent widget to grow or shrink to fit its children.